# flask send_from_directory function keeps sending the same old file

Tags: flask, plotly-dash

I have a flask app that contains a link to download a file from the server. The file will be updated by another callback function. The part for send_from_directory is like this:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
dash_app = dash.Dash(__name__,server=app,url_base_pathname="/",external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
```

...

```
@dash_app.server.route('/download/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def download_data():
    return flask.send_from_directory("../data/",
                                     filename='result.csv',
                                     as_attachment=True,
                                     attachment_filename='result.csv',
                                     cache_timeout=0)
```

I have 2 problems:

1) the file downloaded are always the same old file, despite I have have set the cache timeout as 0.
2) the downloaded file are always named as "download", instead of the file name I specified "result.csv".

Comment: Are you sure the file on the server is changing? Have you tried downloading the file from another web browser?

Comment: Thanks. I moved to another computer and it works well. I found in chrome, I had to clear the browser's download cache in order to let it work properly.

Comment: I've run into the same problem, and I'm sure that the file has indeedly changed on the server (which is my machine, and I opened the data myself to check the update of file). I don't see why moving to another computer might do the trick. I'm on firefox, is the problem the cache browser download ?

Comment: OK, that's the trick, the browser is the problem here, holding the old files versions in memory to not download them again... Pretty annoying, does someone know a workaround that wouldn't be on the user end ? I can see the solution of changing the name of the file downloaded each time, but that's pretty tedious to do.